# Add files to Gradle sourceSets in Kotlin DSL

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have started using Kotlin DSL in my Gradle builds. Before I could write the following in Groovy DSL:

```
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs("src/main/resources").includes.addAll(["**/*.*"])
```

How can I write this in Kotlin DSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Gradle version either

```
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs("src/main/resources").includes.addAll(arrayOf("**/*.*"))
```

or

```
sourceSets.main.configure {
    resources.srcDirs("src/main/resources").includes.addAll(arrayOf("**/*.*"))
}
```

Comment: I use Gradle 6.2. The second one worked for me. Thanks !